# Put an image file on the map in QGIS without coordinates

Tags: qgis, symbology, coordinates, image, svg

Is there any way to put an image file on the map in QGIS 3.12.1 and move it anywhere. For example, there is a map with national parks and I want to add an image (SVG) as a symbol, without coordinates  in it?

Comment: Create a Point layer, edit and Place one Point, symbolize using the svg

Comment: It's not exactly what I was looking for, I meant simply drag and drop an image on the map, scale if needed without collide with other labels. But anyway, it works. Thanks for help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that in the print-composer. There you can insert an image on the top of the map. You can compose different text- and graphic elements to an output as image or graphic file or pdf.

See documentation here: https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/training_manual/map_composer/map_composer.html

Comment: Thank you for your immediate reply. I have more questions in subsequent posts about QGIS. See you next time then!

Comment: @Karol https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers